# Media feature pack for Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows-8.1

I need the media feature pack so I can work with speech recognition, but I can't find it for **Windows 8.1 Pro**, all the links are for `Windows 8.1 N`. Does that means that doesn't exist for **8.1 Pro**?

**Edit:** seems I forgot to mention, the N package won't install on my machine. It says *"The update is not applicable to your computer"*

Answer (score 1):

I think its called [Media Center pack for Windows 8.1](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/09/18/install-media-center-pack-windows-8-1/), but is not a free upgrade.

Type features on the Windows 8.1 start screen and select the "Add features to Windows 8.1" entry from the results.
If you already have a Media Center product key, select "I already have a product key" from the window that opens up on the desktop.
If you need a key, select "I want to buy a product key online" instead and follow the instructions.
Enter the product key on the next page and wait for it to be verified.
The computer will restart if everything turned out to be alright and Windows Media Center will be installed in the process.

Also see this page
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/products/windows-media-center/get-it

Comment: Check out my edit

Comment: [See this](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/09/18/install-media-center-pack-windows-8-1/)